# How to toggle the visibility of the third pane of NavigationView?

Tags: macos, swiftui, appkit

Assuming the following NavigationView:

```swift
Struct ContentView: View {
   @State var showRigthPane: Bool = true 

   var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
           Sidebar()
           MiddlePane()
           RightPane()
       }.toolbar {
           ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
                Button(action: toggleSidebar, label: {Image(systemName: "sidebar.left")})
            }
           ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
               Button(action: self.toggleRightPane, label: { Image() })
           }
       }
   }

   private func toggleRightPane() {
       // ?
   }
   
   // collapsing sidebar - this works
   private func toggleSidebar() {
        NSApp.keyWindow?.initialFirstResponder?.tryToPerform(
            #selector(NSSplitViewController.toggleSidebar(_:)), with: nil)
    }

}
```

How can I implement the `toggleRightPane()` function to toggle the visibility of the right pane?

Comment: Hi there, have you found a good solution for this? Maybe with the new NavigationStack ? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack

Comment: Maybe NavigationSplitView ? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview/

Answer (score 2):

**Updated** to use a calculated property returning two different navigation views. Still odd behavior with sidebar, but with a work-around it is functional. Hopefully someone can figure out the sidebar behavior.

```
struct ToggleThirdPaneView: View {
    @State var showRigthPane: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            navigationView
        }
        .navigationTitle("Show and Hide")
    }
    
    var navigationView : some View {
        if showRigthPane {
            return AnyView(NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    Text("left")
                }
                .toolbar {
                    Button(action: { showRigthPane.toggle() }) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: showRigthPane ? "rectangle.split.3x1" : "rectangle.split.2x1")
                    }
                }
                Text("middle")
            }
            )
        } else {
            return AnyView(NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    Text("left")
                }
                .toolbar {
                    Button(action: { showRigthPane.toggle() }) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: showRigthPane ? "rectangle.split.3x1" : "rectangle.split.2x1")
                    }
                }
                Text("middle")
                Text("right")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach doesn't close the right pane split (which is the third pane of NavigationView). So with your code even after toggling `showRightPane` boolean, there are still three panes remaining with now just an EmptyView for the third pane.

Comment: The code has been updated. Closer, but still not 100%. Please give it a try.

Comment: Yea, this sort of works but like you said sidebar looks odd. I think the solution is to call into NSSplitViewController and collapse a sideview, although I don't know how. I'll edit my question to show how I currently close the sidebar split , maybe it'll be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (cannot test)

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @State private var showRigthPane = true 

   var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
           Sidebar()
           MiddlePane()
           if showRigthPane {    // << here !!
               RightPane()
           }
       }.toolbar {
           ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
               Button(action: self.toggleRightPane, label: { Image() })
           }
       }
   }

   private func toggleRightPane() {
       withAnimation {
          self.showRigthPane.toggle()     // << here !!
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work and still shows three splits, with the right pane empty after the toggle.